# Getting error using $this when not in object context to all methods in a class except __construct() method

Tags: php

I have two classes in separate files. The names of classes and files are: Substitute.php and Models.php. I have some properties in class Substitute.php which I can access using `$this->property_name` in the `__construct()` method without any error. However when I try to access the **same property** in the **another method**(method `test()` in my case(see the code below)) in the **same class** (i.e., class Substitute) I get the error Fatal error: *Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in G:\ROHAN\eTh0\VectorVolunteers\vector\backend\models\Substitute.php:22*. Line 22 being `echo $this->c_day;` in the method `sss()` (I have cut some of the code in the class, adding only the which I thought to be relevant, I'll add rest of the code in case someone requires). I access methods `sss()` and `test()` from the url by `autoloader method` and `class Router` which I have included below too:
Below this line lies the code inside Substitute.php:
EDIT1: I have added another method from Substitute class where also I get the same error.

```
class Substitute extends Models{
    public $user_id, $c_day, $c_date;
    public function __construct(){
        $_SESSION['username']='user2';
        echo 'constructor in class Substitute ran';
        $this->user_id = $this->get_user_id();
        $this->c_day = $this->upcoming_class();
    }
    public function sss(){
        echo $this->c_day;
    }
    public function test(){        
        if(isset($_POST['select_class_subs'])){
            switch ($_POST['select_class_subs']) {
                case 'Next Class':
                    $this->c_date = date('d-M-yy', strtotime(($this->c_day)));
                    break;

                case 'Next-to-next Class':
                    $this->c_date = date('d-M-yy', strtotime(($this->c_day . '+1 week')));
                    break;

                default:
                    echo 'Custom class selected <br>';
                    break;
            }
            if($this->c_date==date('d-M-yy')){
                echo "Sorry, but you cannot post a substitute request for a class that is scheduled to happen on the same day. <br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "Done! <br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT2: The code in the file *config.php* which is required in the `autoloader()` method(See below):

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){$url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);}
require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS . 'bootstrap.php');
```

EDIT2: The code of file *bootstrap.php* which has `autloader()` method:

```
require_once 'config.php';

// Autoloader for classes
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
function autoloader($class_Name){
    if (file_exists (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'core' . DS . $class_Name . '.php')){
        require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS . 'core' . DS . $class_Name . '.php');
    }
    elseif (file_exists (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'models' . DS . $class_Name . '.php')){
        require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS . 'models' . DS . $class_Name . '.php');
    }
    elseif (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'views' . DS . $class_Name . '.php')){
        require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS . 'views' . DS . $class_Name . '.php');
    }
    elseif (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'controllers' . DS . $class_Name . '.php')){
        require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS . 'controllers' . DS . $class_Name . '.php');
    }
    elseif (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'database' . DS . $class_Name . '.php')) {
        require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'database' . DS . $class_Name . '.php');
    }
    elseif (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'reminders' . DS . $class_Name . '.php')) {
        require_once (ROOT . DS . 'backend' . DS .'reminders' . DS . $class_Name . '.php');
    }
    else {echo 'Class does not exist or Class file not found' . '<br>';}
}

// Route the request to router.php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
Router::route($url);
}
```

EDIT2: Code in the file that contains `class Router{}`:

```
class Router{
  private static $controller_name, $method_name;
  public static function route($url){
      if (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] != "") {
        $controller = ucwords($url[0]);
        self::$controller_name = $controller;
        array_shift($url);
      }
      if (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] != "") {
        $method =  ucwords($url[0]);
        self::$method_name = $method;
        array_shift($url);
      }

      $params = $url;

      $init = new self::$controller_name;

      if (method_exists(self::$controller_name, self::$method_name)){
          call_user_func_array([self::$controller_name, self::$method_name], $params);
      }
      else{
        if(self::$method_name!=NULL){
          echo 'The requested method "' . self::$method_name . '" does not exist in ' . '"' . self::$controller_name . '" controller.';
        }
      }
  }
```

Below this lies the code inside Models.php (I have included it in case someone requires. But know that I have extended this class to many other classes and all of the methods in this class work fine without any errors or warning).

```
class Models extends Database {
private $db, $user_id, $table, $rv_id_table_name, $av_id_table_name, $class_day;
    protected function get_user_id(){
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            $username=$_SESSION['username'];
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM volunteers where username=:username';
            $params = [
                'username' => $username
            ];
            $array = $this->query($sql, $params);
            $this->user_id = $array['id'];
            return $this->user_id;
        }
        else{
            echo 'You are not signed in.' . '<br>' . 'Please sign in first.';
        }
    }
    protected function upcoming_class(){
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            $id = $this->get_user_id();
            $params = [
                'id' => $id
            ];
            $sql = 'SELECT class_day FROM volunteers where id=:id';
            $this->class_day = $this->query($sql, $params);
            return $this->class_day['class_day'];
        }
    }
```

I want to know why am I getting the above mentioned error (in Italics) and how to remove it. I asked it because I have been trying since yesterday, with no success.

Comment: Where is your code that's trying to execute the `sss` method?

Comment: @Phil actually I have some other method in that class called ````test```` the code in it is as follows:

Comment: @Phil actually comment is getting longer by 543 characters with the code. I'll add it in the question just a minute.

Comment: @Phil I have added the ````test()```` method in ````class Substitute```` can you please take the pain of re-reading it again. In case you know someone who can solve this can you tag that person here please?

Comment: You were asked for the code that calls the `sss` method. Could you please provide it

Comment: @Phil actually I just deleted the method ````sss()```` because I created it for asking the question the method I am using is ````test()```` and I am calling it by using the URL by a ````class Router```` and it is run after a form is submitted as it is included in ````form action="" ````. But I'll add the ````Router class```` as well as my ````autoloader()```` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried converting the properties `$c_day` and `$c_date` from `class Substitute{}` from `public` to `public static` and instead of using `$this->` to above properties I used `self::` in the methods `public function sss()` and `public function test()` and to my surprise it works. No more errors.

Answer (score 1):

How do you use that method (sss)? Are you by chance calling it statically:

```
Substitute::sss();
```

If so, that is why you are having the issue. The method is not static. It must be called like this (as one example):

```
$object = new Substitute();
$object->sss();
```

Comment: Actually I have an ````autoloader```` method and ````Router```` class that instantiates the class, and the method ````sss```` is actually a form action from another page. And no I.m not calling it statically.